# Ajax Returning different output in same logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying below code to return an array by AJAX and try to alert the return value but its showing me undefined while getting correct value with the same logic.

Here is my both HTML & JS code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
    <input type="button" id="getMI" />    
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS Code (Getting undefined)**

```
var getId = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {
            objLen = res.length;
            var arrElems = [];
            for (i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {

                arrElems[i] = res[i].ids;

            }
            return arrElems;

        },
        error: function (e) {
            return e;
        }
    })
}
```

**JS Code (Getting correct value)**

```
var getId = function(){
 var nums = [];
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {
        nums[i] = i+1;
    }
 return nums;
}
```

**Alerting value**

```
$('#getMI').click(function(){
    var ids = getId();
    alert(ids)      
})
```

> When I directly alert the output (block_faces) its giving me correct
>   value but when I try to return that its showing undefined.

Can anyone help me to know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from an ajax callback.  First of all, it doesn't have anywhere to return *to*.  Second, unless it is synchronous (don't do that), the code that comes *after* the ajax call is likely to execute first and you can't get the value you need.

You must use the success callback to handle all of your post-ajax operations, or you can bind more callbacks to the jqXHR object that is returned via `.done`:

```
var getBlockFaceId = function(){
    return $.ajax({

$("#getBFI").on('click', function () {
    getBlockFaceId().done(function () { alert(ids); });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting all the process and response of an AJAX in alert but not the output I want.

Answer (score 0):

The return keyword returns the value for the current function under which the return is fired. So the return you are writing currently is returning the value for success function.
So define a global variable for js and update that value as shown below

```
var block_faces = '';
        $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url:url,
                        dataType:'json',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success:function(res){
                            objLen = res.length;
                            var block_faces = [];                   
                            for(i=0;i<objLen;i++)
                            {

                                block_faces[i] = res[i].block_face_id;

                            }  

                        },
                        error:function(e){
                            block_faces = e;
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Getting same output (undefined in alert)

Answer (score 0):

Guys I would like to share something I came to know about solution of my issue. To make call successfully I've used **async:false** following one of the suggestion but I got some issues later on. Issue like I was not able to get **success response**  on Safar browser. After posting a question here I came to know that using **async:false** is totally wrong approach.

Here I'm pasting the link of comments and discussion on that.

[Getting error in AJAX response on Safari browser only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996110/getting-error-in-ajax-response-on-safari-browser-only)

Hope it'll help you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The function is finished before the ajax is finished.
Hence "Asynchronous".

You can turn the async off by using that option in jQuery.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

This question was asked before.

Edit:
When combining it with the other answer, which is also correct.

```
var getBlockFaceId = function () {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (res) {
            objLen = res.length;
            var block_faces = [];
            for (i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {

                block_faces[i] = res[i].block_face_id;

            }
            result = block_faces;

        },
        error: function (e) {
            result = e;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

This is both synchronous and it uses a variable to store the result of the inner function.

Comment: I'm getting the same output (undefined in alert)

Comment: I tried it when the process completes like:
`$.ajax({
    complete:function(){
        return block_faces
     }
   })`
still undefined is coming

Comment: then please try to buffer the result in a variable like above.

Comment: Hi Scones, Thanks for your suggestion but its giving empty alert

Comment: Hi Scones, I tried at my home and it works for me, thanks a lot. Now I'll have to check where I went wrong with above code.

Comment: Echoing from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996110/getting-error-in-ajax-response-on-safari-browser-only -- you should *not* use `async:false`. It pretty much defeats the idea of AJAX. Instead use callback functions that continue the program execution when the AJAX call finishes.

Comment: @Juhana The purpose is always defined by the need, not by itself. There are real world uses for turning off the async (ie. to work with libraries, which do not support callbacks). JQuery Validate is an example for that.

Comment: There are use cases that belong in a very small group of exceptions. This is not one of them.

Comment: @Scones I came to know that defining **async:false** is totally wrong approach. I'm posting the link on the answer so you and all other users can see why we should not use that approach.