# Getting error in AJAX response on Safari browser only

Tags: javascript, jquery, httpwebresponse

I'm facing very strange issue. I'm using below code to get value from an API:

```
    var getId = function () {
    var url: "Proxy:url=https_URL"
     var result;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (res) {
                objLen = res.length;
                var arrElems = [];
                for (i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {

                    arrElems[i] = res[i].ids;

                }
                result = arrElems;

            },
            error: function (e) {
                result = e;
            }
        })
       return result;
    }
```

Its responsing as success but when I run this code on Safari its giving an error. Can anyone please help me to find what is the issue and to solve it?

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried doing `arrElems.push(res[i].ids)`?

Comment: Do you realize that there is no point in returning a value from the success or error handlers?  Your getId function has long since finished executing.  The return value from the success or error handlers just goes into the async ajax handling code, not back to your code anywhere.  To use those values, you have to put the code in the handlers or call a function and pass the data to the function.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using that function on click event of a link and now I'm trying with buffering the result in a variable as modified above code. Is it ok or I'm getting you wrong?

Comment: You can't return the result from your `getId()` function.  Ajax is asynchronous (that's what the "A" stands for).  The `getId()` function just starts the ajax call and then it returns immediately.  The success or error handlers are called sometime later, long after the `getId()` function has completed.  I'd really suggest you read up on asynchronous ajax calls.  You can't program them sequentially like you are trying to do.  I don't know if this is your safari problem or not, but it's a major problem in your logic.

Comment: @jfriend00 So you mean to say I should not use async:false?

Comment: @djtechie definitely not use `async:false`. If anything, it kills performance. I think it's removed from jQuery 1.9 as well

Comment: @JanDvorak Hi Jan, thanks to look at the code but then I'm not getting an issue in result

Comment: You return the `result` before it gets its intended value. That's why you're getting an `undefined` return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this function returning "undefined"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143580/why-is-this-function-returning-undefined)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776436/ajax-returning-different-output-in-same-logic please see this question

Comment: @djtechie You were given bad advice.

Comment: @djtechie `async:false` is bad for performance and, IIRC, deprecated. Better refactor your logic. Either accept a callback or return a promise. Promises are more versatile.

Comment: The return value of `$.ajax` is a promise: An object where you can submit callbacks, and they will be executed when the ajax is complete.